# AS3 to JS compilers

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I stumbled accroos the AS3 to JS compiler [Jangaroo](http://www.jangaroo.net/home/), which looks like it could be a useful tool since it supports a lot of things I like about AS3.

- Are there any other such compilers?
- Is there another language I could
  learn, that compiles to JS, that is
  AS3 like?

Comment: Try this new tool for convert your as3 application to js html5 https://github.com/AntonovSergey2211/guepard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Haxe](http://haxe.org)

From the intro page:

> Haxe (pronounced as hex) is an open
>   source programming language.
>
> While most other languages are bound
>   to their own platform (Java to the
>   JVM, C# to .Net, ActionScript to the
>   Flash Player), Haxe is a multiplatform
>   language.
>
> It means that you can use Haxe to
>   target the following platforms :
>
> Javascript : You can compile a Haxe
>   program to a single .js file. You can
>   access the typed browser DOM APIs with
>   autocompletion support, and all the
>   dependencies are resolved at
>   compilation time.
>
> Flash : You can compile a Haxe program
>   to a .swf file. Haxe can compile for
>   Flash Players 6 to 10, with either
>   "old" Flash<8 API or newest
>   AS3/Flash9+ API. Haxe offers very good
>   performance and language features to
>   develop Flash content.
>
> NekoVM : You can compile a Haxe
>   program to NekoVM bytecode. This can
>   be used for server-side programming
>   such as dynamic webpages (using
>   mod_neko for Apache) and also for
>   commandline or desktop applications,
>   since the NekoVM can be embedded and
>   extended with some other DLL.
>
> PHP : You can compile a Haxe program
>   to .php files. This enable you to use
>   a high level strictly-typed language
>   such as Haxe while keeping full
>   compatibility with your existing
>   server platform and libraries.
>
> C++ : You can now generate C++ code
>   from your Haxe source code, with the
>   required Makefiles. This is very
>   useful for creating native
>   applications, for instance in iPhone
>   development.

Also of possible interest to you: [Haxer](http://github.com/Atmospherian/Haxer), a java project i wrote that helps convert AS3 code to Haxe code. It is not complete, but it gives you a good start in converting your code.

Comment: great thanks, forgot all about haXe after reading about a while back - it sounds fantastic, but do a lot of people use it? and does it have a future? Haxer sounds interesting too - will def check out. (btw your blog seems to be offline at the mo)

Comment: i really can't say how much it is used, but i use it, and love it. I think it's future really depends on the libraries that are available for it to get people excited about using it. Like with Ruby, it didn't become widely used/known about until Rails came along. I've actually been thinking about researching an MVC based web framework based on haXe that could share components with Flash/Flex and create some kind of neat synergy between the client and server.

Answer (score 1):

Tadster made an AS3 to JavaScript set of AS3 classes, the com.actiontadJS.converter package.

You have to be pretty good at AS3 to understand and use it well.

But the package of classes has been available for some time and it works pretty good, it produces OOP JavaScript, but does not convert imports or inheritance, so it's good for writing JavaScript Classes in AS3 first, takes away some of the tedium of writing OOP JavaScript.

http://www.actiontad.com/basicGameObjects/

Answer (score 0):

C# to JS
http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Answer (score 0):

I should say that TypeScript is pretty similar to AS3 as a language and it's on the wave right now, so I guess it won't be abandoned in the near future. I suggest you try that.