# Decode AS3 into Jquery

Tags: jquery, flash

I have project in Flash .it is not supported to ipad.now i want to covert it into jquery/html or do in need to write it From Scratch.Please give me suggestion what should i Do ? Redevelop or is there any way to convert ?

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use flash app on iPad, you can compile it for iOS with Adobe AIR. This way, you won't rewrite too much (nevertheless, you'll probably face several bugs need to be fixed). There are also some AS3 to HTML5 translators, so one of them can be your choice. And of course, you can redevelop your project from scratch in Objective-C. As for me, first variant is the best one.

If you need to convert you AS3 code to JS, [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863454/as3-to-js-compilers) may help you.

Comment: Actually there are other requirement in project. i know JQuery /HTML file . that's the Reason First i want to convert that Flash file into Jquery...   any suggestion ??

Comment: So, you want to convert your SWF to JS library?